# How to change the two switch data with click with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Please can someone teach me the method to swap two different data on click

For example, we have a data

```js
data() {
        return {

          data_one: [
            {
              name: "Simo",
              age: "32"
            }
          ],

          data_two: [
            {
              name: "Lisa",
              age: "25"
            }
          ],

        }
      },
```

then I want to put this data on `v-for`, and I want to add two buttons to swap from data_one and data_two and display data_one as default.

```html
<button @click="change_to_data_one">Data 1<button>
<button @click="change_to_data_two">Data 2<button>

<li v-for="item in data_one">{{item.name}} - {{item.age}}<li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use computed property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      data_one: [{name: "Simo", age: "32"}],
      data_two: [{name: "Lisa", age: "25"}],
      selected: "data_one"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    showData(){
      return this[this.selected]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    swap(val) {
      this.selected = val
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="swap('data_one')">Data 1</button>
  <button @click="swap('data_two')">Data 2</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in showData" :key="i">{{item.name}} - {{item.age}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: just wrap the `ul` in `li` otherwise it will be invalid HTML

Comment: Awesome, easy to understand, nice explanation, Thank you so much 